# Label width in TableView not shrink according to sizeToFit autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am trying to make a chatview with table but my label width not responded to its width.

**constraints for label**

[image]

**constraints for bubbleview**

[image]

**code**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     //...... some code here
     oLblMessage.text=chat.iText;
     [oLblMessage sizeToFit]; // this doesn't responded at sll
     NSLog(@"%f",oLblMessage.frame.size.width);
     [oLblMessage layoutIfNeeded];
     [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
     return cell;
}
```

**result**

[image]

**Even I tried to set priorities but not succeeded.**

SO any solution for this....

Comment: remove fixed width constraint , give it leading and trailing

Comment: its equal width constraint not fix one

Comment: Just need to change the leading constraint to trailing for the label.

Comment: no it doesn't work ... i did try

Comment: did you remove that width constriant  ?

Comment: remove width constraint , and give trailing , no need for size to fit,text alignment to right

Comment: @MikeAlter its  not a fix width ... that width is when my label shrinks, according to that my bubble view also responds ... thats why that equal width constraint is there

Comment: i understand that  on first time , this is not required constraint , because if you give that constraint  your label will never changes its width according to text

Comment: @MikeAlter let me try...

Comment: @MikeAlter so what is the possible solution

Comment: as i told you give constraint like that , because it will help  calculate the width for your label

Comment: @MikeAlter i did try but that not working

Comment: what is result , same ?

Comment: @MikeAlter yes same result ... not change anythibg

Comment: it should work , make sure you have not fixed any thing , not even blue view width

Comment: @MikeAlter nothing has fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your constraints as below

for Bubble:

[For Bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL4lG.png)

for Label:

[image: for label]

Maybe this will help you..

Comment: You have the same image for both. Please [edit] your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Idan for suggetion

Answer (score 2):

sizeToFit will not set it width according to text size becauase of current constraints. Add width constraint in label, and make it less than or equal to. in cellForRowAtIndexpath calculate size of text and assign size.width to lableWidth contstraint constant through its iboutlet.

Comment: it had worked for me, you will have to apply some constraint logic accordingly

Comment: or add trailing constraint in label and change that equal width constraint to less than or equal to. try it, then size to fit should work